# C++ Windows API Syscall Hook Example

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system-calls

Im just starting to learn C++ programming and for exercise I want to learn how to write Windows API Syscall Hook. For example, if I will try to delete a file with a specific name, for exmaple 'test.txt', then instead of deleting it a message would pop up. I tried searching for a tutorial on how to do something like that but I couldn't find anything.

Maybe someone could share a link to a tutorial on how to do something like this or maybe a very simple code example?

I am working on Windows 10 machine and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: This more has to do with windows API and windows related libraries than C++ on its own. You might need to learn about winforms for the pop up.

Comment: As far as I am aware, Windows doesn't support this as part of its API, in contrast to Linux; there are a few targeted approaches for very specific subsets of the Windows API (such as creating a custom driver to intercept file IO), and a few low-level approaches that work at the thunk level and require knowledge of x86/x64 assembler.  Just out of curiosity, why do you think this can be done in a simple code example?

Comment: This is possible, but very difficult.  It is not an appropriate project for a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a **File System (Mini-)Filter Driver**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> A file system filter driver is an optional driver that adds value to
>   or modifies the behavior of a file system. A file system filter driver
>   is a kernel-mode component that runs as part of the Windows executive.
>
> A file system filter driver can filter I/O operations for one or more
>   file systems or file system volumes. Depending on the nature of the
>   driver, filter can mean log, observe, modify, or even prevent. Typical
>   applications for file system filter drivers include antivirus
>   utilities, encryption programs, and hierarchical storage management
>   systems.

The windows driver samples contain a minifilter driver to detect deletions of files or streams.

See: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/delete